# Getting the current key of a map entry given another equivalent key object

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

Suppose I have a `HashMap<K, V>` and two objects of type `K` that are equal to each other but not the same object, and the map has an entry for key `k1`.

Given `k2`, can I get a reference to `k1` using only methods from `HashMap` (no external data structures) that executes in constant time, ie O(1) time complexity?

In code:

```
K k1, k2;
k1.equals(k2) // true
k1.hashCode() == k2.hashCode() // true
k1 == k2 // false
myMap.put(k1, someValue);

K existingKey = getExistingKey(myMap, k2);
existingKey == k1 // true <- this is the goal

<K> K getExistingKey(HashMap<K, V> map, K k) {
    // What impl goes here?
}
```

I was hoping to use one of the various methods added with java 8, such as `compute()` to "sniff" the existing key within the lambda, but they all (seem to) pass the *new* key object to the lambda, not the existing key.

Iterating through the `entrySet()` would find the existing key, but not in constant time.

I could use a `Map<K, K>` to store the keys and I could keep it in sync, but that doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Is this even possible? `k1.equals(k2) // true
k1.hashCode() == k2.hashCode() // true
k1 == k2 // false`

Comment: Of course it's possible, and this is the case for the vast majority of object comparisons.  `k1==k2` only if it's the same object instance.

Comment: It might help if you explained the use case where this would be important.  Is there other state in `k2` not forming part of `equals()/hashCode()` that you need to access?  That sort of breaks the  implicit contract for those methods.

Comment: @CardinalSystem example: `List<String> a = Arrays.asList("foo"); List<String> b = Arrays.asList("foo");` would obey those conditions.

Comment: @Jim I'm implementing a DAWG and the keys are subtrees in a graph. I need the reference to the existing tree to reuse the same exact object.

Comment: It hardly has any meaning to restrict the solution to have no explicit external data structures, since if you can get a peer keys, thus there is a data structure is held alongside that contains these keys. I would suggest you to implement your variation of a `Map` interface that supports such retrieval facility by means of maintaining a separate collection of peer keys.

Comment: I don't think you have a choice, either call `getNode` via reflection (which is a pain and could break later - it *was* named `getEntry` before...) or use `entrySet`

Comment: @Pavel there will be millions of nodes - it's a memory usage issue.

Comment: @Eugene AFAIK there has never been a public method called `getEntry()` on any `Map` in java.

Comment: I've done a search to find the exact version where it was renamed, and stumbled across https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873330/why-is-getentryobject-key-not-exposed-on-hashmap

Comment: I never said it was public btw

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner and how, *exactly*, would I do that without an external data structure? I have many thousands of keys, possibly millions. I want to save memory. As per my question, I could put all the keys in a map of key -> key (like what backs a set), but that solution is out of scope.

Comment: @Bohemian, it is not possible to save memory restricting the solution. As I said, if you'd like to get all peer keys to the one you've provided, it should be stored in memory anyway. Thus, a custom implementation of a `Map` interface that stores peer keys explicitly would not take more space in memory.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for something like

```
Map.Entry<K,V> getEntry(K key)
```

At first I thought it would be easy to make a custom subclass of `HashMap` to return this, as `get(K key)` is just

```
public V get(Object key) {
     Node<K,V> e;
     return (e = getNode(hash(key), key)) == null ? null : e.value;
}
```

where `Node` implements `Map.Entry`.  This would look like:

```
public class MyHashMap<K,V> extends HashMap<K,V>
{
    public MyHashMap() {}
    // Other constructors as needed

    public Map.Entry<K, V> getEntry(K key)
    {
        Map.Entry<K, V> e = getNode(hash(key),key);
        return e;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, `getNode()` and `hash()` are both package private and therefore not visible to subclasses.

The next step was to put the class in `java.util` but this fails in Java 9 with

```
The package java.util conflicts with a package accessible from another module: java.base
```

I think you're out of luck here.

I actually think a `getEntry()` method would be a useful addition to the API, you might consider filing an enhancement request.

Comment: To circumvent package private, you could create such a class in the package `java.util` in your own project. Why not enhance your answer with that in mind. Also, make the method `getKey()` - getting the value is trivial.

Comment: Already tried that. This fails in Java 9 with modules, the error is `The package java.util conflicts with a package accessible from another module: java.base`.  If there's a way around that I haven't been able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how constrained you are regarding memory usage, but if you can use a `LinkedHashMap` instead of a `HashMap` (`LinkedHashMap` uses extra references to keep insertion order), then you could take advantage of its [`removeEldestEntry`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#removeEldestEntry-java.util.Map.Entry-) method:

```
public class HackedMap<K, V> extends LinkedHashMap<K, V> {

    K lastKey;

    @Override
    protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<K, V> eldest) {
        lastKey = eldest.getKey();
        return false;
    }

    K getLastKey() {
        return lastKey;
    }
}
```

I think the code is self-explanatory. We are keeping a reference to the original key, which we grab from the `removeEldestEntry` method's argument.
As to the `removeEldestEntry` method's return value, it is `false`, so that we don't allow the eldest entry to be removed (after all, we don't want the map to work as a cache).

Now, with a common insertion-order `LinkedHashMap`, the `removeEldestEntry` method is automatically called by `put` and `putAll` (from `removeEldestEntry` method docs):

> This method is invoked by put and putAll after inserting a new entry into the map.

So all we need to do now is to implement your `getExistingKey` method in such a way that it calls `put` without modifying the map, which you can do as follows:

```
<K, V> K getExistingKey(HackedMap<K, V> map, K k) {
    if (k == null) return null;
    V v = map.get(k);
    if (v == null) return null;
    map.put(k, v);
    return map.getLastKey();
}
```

This works because, when the map already contains an entry mapped to a given key, the `put` method replaces the value without touching the key.

I'm not sure about the null checks I've done, maybe you need to improve that. And of course this `HackedMap` doesn't support concurrent access, but `HashMap` and `LinkedHashMap` don't do either.

You can safely use a `HackedMap` instead of a `HashMap`. This is the test code:

```
Key k1 = new Key(10, "KEY 1");
Key k2 = new Key(10, "KEY 2");
Key k3 = new Key(10, "KEY 3");

HackedMap<Key, String> myMap = new HackedMap<>();

System.out.println(k1.equals(k2)); // true
System.out.println(k1.equals(k3)); // true
System.out.println(k2.equals(k3)); // true

System.out.println(k1.hashCode() == k2.hashCode()); // true
System.out.println(k1.hashCode() == k3.hashCode()); // true
System.out.println(k2.hashCode() == k3.hashCode()); // true

System.out.println(k1 == k2); // false
System.out.println(k1 == k3); // false
System.out.println(k2 == k3); // false

myMap.put(k1, "k1 value");
System.out.println(myMap); // {Key{k=10, d='KEY 1'}=k1 value}

myMap.put(k3, "k3 value"); // Key k1 (the one with its field d='KEY 1') remains in
                           // the map but value is now 'k3 value' instead of 'k1 value'

System.out.println(myMap); // {Key{k=10, d='KEY 1'}=k3 value}

Key existingKey = getExistingKey(myMap, k2);

System.out.println(existingKey == k1); // true
System.out.println(existingKey == k2); // false
System.out.println(existingKey == k3); // false

// Just to be sure
System.out.println(myMap); // {Key{k=10, d='KEY 1'}=k3 value}
```

---

Here's the `Key` class I've used:

```
public class Key {

    private final int k;

    private final String d;

    Key(int k, String d) {
        this.k = k;
        this.d = d;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Key key1 = (Key) o;
        return k == key1.k;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(k);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Key{" +
                "k=" + k +
                ", d='" + d + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought about this, in the sense of using `TreeMap#ceilingEntry`

Comment: Your suggestion doesn't "satisfy all my requirements"; it puts the new key object into the map, but I never want to overwrite an existing key. Instead, I want to put a new value without affecting the key. That way, the map functions as a cache with metadata/attributes. If I encounter a key collision, I want to throw away my new key and use the key object already in the map.

Comment: @Bohemian right. I would honestly go the reflective call of the the method, also providing a unit test as a safety net in case it gets changed.

Comment: @Bohemian You are wrong. The key is never overwritten when there's already an entry mapped to an equal key. Let me modify the testing code and you'll see...

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner I was not referring to the overriding part - I *know* it is not overridden.

Comment: @Eugene Agreed: reflection plus unit tests, especially to guard against changes to the way hash codes are actually used, is where I'm going

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner its too late for me to think.. will take a closer look tomorrow